# Loading phar libraries - temp permissions

Tags: php, macos, osx-mountain-lion, phar

I'm having problems loading a Phar library. The error suggested a permissions issue for temp files, so I temporarily chmod to 777 the relevant directory (found using sys_get_tmp_dir()) and it works.

```
include('phar://PHPStats/PHPStats.phar/lib/ProbabilityDistribution/Beta.php');
$beta = new \PHPStats\ProbabilityDistribution\Beta(6,20);
```

I'm trying to use this library: https://github.com/mcordingley/PHPStats

What's the correct way to enable the webserver to write to the directory, so that I can use phar?

My system is Mac OSX Mountain Lion.

Comment: try without the phar:// inside the include. Otherwise post the php line in phar library where the file is included so that we can see what's giving the error. "the tmp folder seem fine" is a bit vague.

Comment: if it says it does not have permissions on the tmp dir, it obviously doesn't... try `is_writable(sys_get_temp_dir())`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I had the wrong tmp dir. I'll amend the question...